# How can I use @BeforeTest for Capabilities class / or correctly extends on each @Test

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium

I would like to create one class in which to insert `@BeforeTest Capabilities`. Referencing the below code, it is easy to insert tests into `@Test`.
Without `TestNG` everything works, but it doesn't work with `TestNG`.
Maybe I misunderstood something?

Class with Capabilities

```
public class test {

        public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {

            File f =new File("src");
            File fs = new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "demo");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver= new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

             return driver;
        }
```

Test example with extends Capabilities From test

```
public class swiping extends test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=Capabilities();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']").click();

        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Date Widgets']").click();

        driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"2. Inline\")").click();

        driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='9']").click();

         Thread.sleep(1000);

        TouchAction t=new TouchAction(driver);

        WebElement first=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='15']");
        WebElement second=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='45']");
        t.longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(first)).withDuration(ofSeconds(2))).moveTo(element(second)).release().perform();
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe this is the approach you have used without Testng. Could you please share the approach you tried with Testng?

Comment: Yep, this example without TestNg, because i dont know how to correctly introduce class with Capabilities into @Beforetest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example shows a TestNG example of how to do the same thing.

The example leverages `ThreadLocal` so that tomorrow if you decide to run multiple `@Test` methods in parallel wherein every `@Test` method needs its own `AndroidDriver` instance, this would still work.

```java
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions.longPressOptions;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;
import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;

import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassExample {

  //We use thread local so that even if you decide to run tests in parallel, every @Test method
  //will get its own AndroidDriver instance
  private static final ThreadLocal<AndroidDriver> drivers = new ThreadLocal<>();

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setupDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    File f = new File("src");
    File fs = new File(f, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "demo");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
    AndroidDriver driver =
        new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    drivers.set(driver);
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void cleanupDriver() {
    drivers.get().quit();
    drivers.remove();
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() throws InterruptedException {
    AndroidDriver driver = drivers.get();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']").click();

    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Date Widgets']").click();

    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"2. Inline\")").click();

    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='9']").click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);

    WebElement first = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='15']");
    WebElement second = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@content-desc='45']");
    t.longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(first)).withDuration(ofSeconds(2)))
        .moveTo(element(second))
        .release()
        .perform();
  }
}
```

PS: You should not be using `@BeforeTest` because that gets executed only once per `<test>` tag. You are better off using either a `@BeforeClass` (which gets executed once per test class (or) a `@BeforeMethod` (which gets executed once per `@Test` method)

Comment: wow , it's really cool ,Thanks but i faced another problem ( Maybe you can help me with this ?

 FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setupDriver org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' 

My pom file pastebin.com/0QHtyHKv
appium logs https://pastebin.com/GETq7S5c

Comment: Can you please post it as a new question since I don't think the current question is related to this new issue you are experiencing.